# Term for dilemma regarding knowledge of information which cannot be used without alerting the other party

Tags: terminology

What is the term for a dilemma in which one has crucial information belonging to another party, who would be alerted if any sort of action were to be taken regarding this information?

An example of this predicament would be in World War II, where the Allies had broken the Enigma Code. However, if the Allies were to attempt to counter any of the German attacks using their newfound information, the Germans would know that their code had been broken and consequently alter the cipher.

This term was mentioned in the "Imitation Game", however, I cannot seem to find it again.

Comment: Such a dilemma could be described as a **double-edged sword**. "something that has or can have both favorable and unfavorable consequences". However, this would be referring more to the fact that something bad for the Allies would happen if they used the "weapon" they possessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "Coventry dilemma" has been used in this context (e.g. [here](http://www.coventrytelegraph.net/news/10-things-named-after-inspired-9545786)), after the supposed decision by Churchill in the Blitz not to give the city of Coventry any extra defences even though he knew from Ultra intercepts that it was about to be heavily bombed.  Declassified material has revealed that he never had such information in the first place, but the phrase remains; nobody knows what Churchill would have done if he had really faced a Coventry dilemma.

Comment: Ah, yes! This was it!